# Iterating through output from 'dir' concatenates User and Folder name

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory

The following loop does not always generate just the creator user. A lot of times it concatenates the user with the folder. I don't know if it's some kind of limitation of batch or am I missing something

```
for /f "tokens=5,* SKIP=4" %%b IN ('dir "%folder%" /Q /TW /AD') do (
    ECHO User: %%b
)
```

about 90-95% of the time it is giving me the user, but other times it is giving me user_folder

```
User: AAAAAAAAAADEV\iasimo_dFLD001_FLD001
```

- FLD001_FLD001 is the folder name
- AAAAAAAAAADEV\iasimo_d is the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up doing it a little dumber way - it seems the user column is 22 chars, and whenever the domain/username hits that I get that problem. I resolved it by taking everything after the username as a single token, then just chop off everything after 22nd char (the below code is to get the folder name - basically same thing but I needed both so that's how I got it).

```
for /f "tokens=1-4,* SKIP=4" %%b IN ('dir "%%a" /Q /TW /AD') do (
        set _folder=%%f
        SET _folder=!_folder:~23!
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably because the dir columns are with fixed size.
Would suggest you to use another aproach

1)WMIC  :

```
@echo off

set "folder=C:\Windows\System32"

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("%folder%") do (
     set "fpath=%%~pa"
     set "fname=%%~na"
     set "fdrive=%%~da"
)

set "fpath=%fpath:\=\\%"

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in (`wmic path Win32_Directory where "path='%fpath%' and drive='%fdrive%' and filename='%fname%'" get  CSName /format:value`) do (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%z in  ("%%a") do (

        if "%%z" neq "" (
            set "%%z"
        )
    )
)

echo %CSName%
```

2)  [tooltipInfo.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/tooltipInfo.bat).To to get a folder/file owner youl need to use the 10 "magic number" (10 is of the owner 174 is for the creator):

```
call tooltipInfo.bat "c:\something" 10
```

should you give you output like:

```
c:\something :
pc\user
```

there are also other possible approaches.

Comment: I have tried to do #1 - but I am having issues. The folder I am looking at is on a shared network (so address from explorer would be \\server01\z\blabla) would this change the wmic query? (apologies this is my first experience with wmic - never used it before)

for number2, I think this would be my last resort, I want to limit the amount of external scripts outside of my batch script, and I am already using an external vb script (I might just have to use this one though)

Comment: @StanM Try first to map the network folder with `net use` command

Comment: This tool will be run on other computers on other networks as well, and they may not have permissions on those computers to do new mappings. I just posted a different way I did that looks like it will work for me (although I'm going to save tooltipInfo.bat just in case, that looks to be really useful)

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=4 SKIP=4" %%b IN ('dir "%folder%" /Q /TW /AD') do (
    ECHO User: %%b
)
```

This works in my system (where the User is column #4).

EDIT: Tested both in Win 7 and in Win 8.1

Comment: I am guessing your domain/user is most likely short, I've only seen it happen with longer domain/usernames

Comment: You are right. Is very short. Have you tried without the `,*` in `tokens=5,*`?

Comment: That probably means there is no delimiter character (i.e., a space)  between both the name and the user and thus, the `FOR` logic "thinks" there is only one token there (user & folder) and that is what it returns. So. The size of the user names are probably to "blame" (so to speak) here.